# How to change the domain of the Many2one field by inheritance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, stock, odoo-11

What I mean is that;

Model with name "stock.return.picking" has "location_id" field.

When I click on the return button , I want to see all the location_id. But location_id has domain:

```
location_id = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='stock.location',
    string='Return Location',
    domain="['|', ('id', '=', original_location_id),'&', ('return_location', '=', True), ('id', 'child_of',     parent_location_id)]"
)
```

How can I change this domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to redefine the `location_id` field, inheriting from `stock.return.picking` model. You could do something like this:

```
location_id = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='stock.location',
    domain="[('id', '!=', 0)]",
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. Sometimes I need to think simple :)

Comment: Why not domain="[]" ?

Comment: @QuentinTHEURET actually because I wasn't sure if that worked and didn't try it, but of course, if it works, that would be a better solution.